# Evaluate $I(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{xv}}{1+e^v}dv$

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus

This is the last part of a multistage evaluation of $I(x)=\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)$. Through various substitutions we get the integral
$$I(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{xv}}{1+e^v}dv$$

We're also given a suggested contour for this integral that is a rectangle in the complex plane with counter-clockwise path of integration from $(-R,0)$ to $(+R,0)$ on the x-axis (where $R=\infty$) then up $2\pi$ units to corner $(R,2\pi i)$ then back to the 2nd quadrant to point $(-R,2\pi i)$ and finally back to the starting point at $(-R,0)$. On the x-axis contour $z=x$ and on the upper contour we're given that $z=x+2\pi i$. We are also told to use residues.

Given this information i just let $z=v$ so $dz=dv$ and our integral becomes 
$$I(x)=\oint\frac{e^{xz}}{1+e^z}dz$$ 
We have a simple pole $z_0=\pi i$ so i evaluated $I$ as
$$I(x)=2\pi i Res\left[\frac{e^{xz}}{1+e^z},z=z_0\right]=2\pi i e^{i\pi(x-1)}$$

I checked my solution by letting $x=1/2$ because we know that $I(1/2)=\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(1-1/2)=\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(1/2)=\pi$
But when i tried my solution i end up with $I(1/2)=2\pi$.

I'm pretty sure my problem is that i treated the $x-axis$ path as a contour by itself which enclosed the pole when it isn't a circular contour. So how do i remedy this situation? How do i include the upper half of the contour while using Residues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $0<t<1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{R\to \infty}\oint_C \frac{e^{tz}}{1+e^z}\,dz&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{tx}}{1+e^{x}}\,dx-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{t(x+2i\pi)}}{1+e^{x+i2\pi}}\,dx\\\\
&=\left(1-e^{i2\pi t}\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{tx}}{1+e^{x}}\,dx \tag 1\\\\
&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{tz}}{1+e^z},z=i\pi\right) \\\\
&=-2\pi i e^{i\pi t} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{tx}}{1+e^x}\,dx&=2\pi i \frac{e^{i\pi t}}{e^{i2\pi it}-1}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi t)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I see how you factored $(1-e^{i2\pi t})$ out of the numerators but how did the $i2\pi$ term out of the exponent in the denominator to arrive at eqn (1)?

Comment: In the denominator, we have $e^{x+i2\pi }=e^xe^{i2\pi}=e^x$.

Comment: Oooh... Because $e^{i2\pi}=1$ . I see! Thank you! I had tried doing the substitution you did but i didn't realize i had to factor out that term and then equate the solution with the integrals. Thank you!

Comment: You're quite welcome!  It was my pleasure.  -Mark